# Python PyQt5 Issues. (Menu, Scaling)

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I'm using PyQt5 and I can't get buttons to work properly.
The code relevant to my button is:

```
    Import_Deck = QPushButton("Import Deck", self)
    Import_Deck.resize(150, 50)
    Import_Deck.clicked.connect(self.importdeck)
    layout.addWidget(Import_Deck, 0, 0)
```

And the issue there is it doesn't resize though it does show up in my window. Nor does putting `layout.addWidget(Import_Deck, 0, 40)` move it. I've tried `QtGeometry(Import_Deck, 0, 0, H, W)`; `QtGeometry(Import_Deck, H, W, 0, 0)`; `QtGeometry(Import_Deck, X, Y, 0, 0)`; `QtGeometry(Import_Deck, 0, 0, X, Y)`. (X, Y, H, and W where all replaced with actual numbers. I just put variables for examples sake.)
I also can't figure out how to make the menu box work either.

```
    formatmenu = QToolButton()
    formatmenu.setText("Formats")
    formatmenu.setMenu(menu)
    formatmenu.setPopupMode(QToolButton.MenuButtonPopup)
    layout.addWidget(formatmenu, 0, 0)
```

And main menu bars don't seem to work for me either. I tried copy and pasting example code, but it didn't work.

```
def mainmenufunc(self):
        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('Decklist')
        editMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('Probability')
        viewMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('Reccomnended Mana')
        self.show()
```

I have no clue what my issue is, as I've reference quite a few different guides trying to fix these issues. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

MRE code:

```
import json
import numpy as np
import math
import os
import PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 2000, 992)
        self.setWindowTitle("MTGCalc")
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        Import_Deck = QPushButton("Import Deck", self)
        Import_Deck.resize(150, 50)
        Import_Deck.adjustSize()
        layout.addWidget(Import_Deck, 0, 0, 0, -100)
        self.mainmenufunc()

    def mainmenufunc(self):
        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('Decklist')
        editMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('Probability')
        viewMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('Reccomnended Mana')
        self.show()
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

screen = Window()
screen.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())

_main_()
```

This error gives: `AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'menuBar'`.
Button issue:

```
#self.mainmenufunc()

    #def mainmenufunc(self):
    #    mainMenu = self.menuBar()
    #    fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('Decklist')
    #    editMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('Probability')
    #    viewMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('Reccomnended Mana')
    #    self.show()
```

all this is commented out from the one above.
The Menubutton literally just doesn't show up even when it is in, so I don't know what to do for that other than:

```
        formatslider = QToolButton()
        formatslider.setText("Formats")
        formatslider.setMenu(menu)
        formatslider.setPopupMode(QToolButton.MenuButtonPopup)
        layout.addWidget(formatslider, 0, 0)
```

all this is added in.

Comment: `resize()` is useless if you're putting a widget into a layout. Besides that, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Musicamante, I added code to elaborate further.